# Neo4j create new node with relationships to more than one other node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relational-database, nodes, graph-databases

I'm trying to create a new node, and at once create two (or more) relationships between this new node and existing nodes:

```
MATCH(n:ElementA), (m:ElementB) 
WHERE n.name = $element.ElementAName 
AND m.name = $element.ElementBName 
MERGE (
    a:ElementNew { 
            id: $element.ElementId,
            NameA: $element.ElementAName, 
            NameB: $element.ElementBName 
        }
    )
-[:CONTAINED_IN]->(m) -[:IS_ON]->(n)
```

It works without relationships, or just with the CONTAINED_IN relationship, but not with both.

I am trying to create 2 relationships, one between the `new node` and node `n` and one between the `new node` and node `m`, not 2 relationships to the same node `n` or `m`.

What is wrong in my syntax?

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Please ask about 1 case of bad code per question. Saying you tried or researched is not helpful. Summarize exactly how you searched & give details of findings applicable to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the syntax written in the question itself is the correct one for this functionality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).